# React-native Navigation Add Hamburger Icon

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-router

Im tring to add Hamburger icon to open Drawer on react-native.but im getting this error

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {left}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

```
Check the render method of `View`.
```

This is routes.js

```
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const DrawerIcon = ({ navigate }) => {

return(
        <Icon
            name = "md-menu"
            size = {38}
            color = "black"
            style = {{paddingLeft : 20}}
            onPress = {() => navigate('DrawerOpen')}
/>

    );
};

export const Stack1 = StackNavigator({
    Screen1: {
        screen: screen1,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: ( props ) => ({
                left: <DrawerIcon { ...props } />
            }),
        }
    },
    Screen2: {
        screen: screen2,
    },
    Screen3: {
        screen: screen3,
    },



})

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Home:{
        screen: Stack1,
        navigationOption: {
            brawerLabel: 'Home',

        }
    },
    Camera:{
        screen: Stack2,
         navigationOption: {
            brawerLabel: 'Camera',

        }
    },
    Info:{
        screen: Stack3,
         navigationOption: {
            brawerLabel: 'Info',
        }
    }
})
```

How can i solve this error.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerTitle: "Home",
    ...css.header,
    headerLeft:
    <View style={{paddingLeft:16}}>
        <Icon
            name="md-menu"
            size={30}
            color='white'
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} />
    </View>,
})
```

in the style.js class i added the constant call header

```
export const header = {
  // background
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: colors.secondary_blue,
  },
  // arrows
  headerTintColor: colors.text_light,
  // my own styles for titleAndIcon
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',

    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingLeft: 8,
  },
  // my own styles for titleAndIcon
  text: {

    paddingLeft: 8,
    color: colors.text_light,
    fontFamily: values.font_body,
    fontSize: values.font_title_size,
  }

};
```

Answer (score 6):

None of the previous answers are very scalable, so thought I'd weigh in with my solution. For completeness, I'm using `react-native-vector-icons` in my example.

```
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';

const MenuIcon = ({ navigate }) => <Icon 
    name='three-bars' 
    size={30} 
    color='#000' 
    onPress={() => navigate('DrawerOpen')}
/>;

const Stack = {
    FirstView: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerRight: MenuIcon(navigation)
        })
    }
};

// ...Remaining navigation code etc.
```

This makes the assumption that you'd want the same icon to open the drawer (which really should be the majority use-case).

Answer (score 4):

I use React Native Elements...provides some cool icons to spice up the menu.  It comes with a lot of preset icons.

```
import { createStackNavigator,createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItems, SafeAreaView  }   from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
```

Here I have StackNavigator called AboutNavigator…

```
const AboutNavigator = createStackNavigator({
About:{ screen:About }
},{
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#512DA8"
},
headerTitleStyle: {
    color: "#fff"            
},
headerTintColor: "#fff",
headerLeft: <Icon name='menu' size={24} color='white'
   onPress={()=> navigation.toggleDrawer()}
   />
})  
})
```

You'll have to install react-native-vector-icons from npm or yarn.  But yes, there is actually a hamburger icon in there.  Where I have named the icon 'menu', you use 'hamburger'.

Here's what the hamburger icon looks like. https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

In the search box, type hamburger.

Answer (score 2):

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle: "User Index",
        headerRight: <Button title="Info" onPress={()=> alert('right button')} />,
    };
    render(){
        return(<UserTabNavigator />);
    }
};
```

---

I had the same problem, the above worked for me

Pay close attention to this line

`headerRight: <Button title="Info" onPress={()=> alert('right button')} />,`

Comment: but when i call `this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')` in side `headerRight: <Button title="Info" onPress={()=> alert('right button')} />,` im getting `undifined is not object (eveluvating '_this2.props.navigation')`

Comment: you can do like this

static navigationOptions = function (props) {

        return {

            title: 'Dashboard Screen',

            headerRight: <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
                onPress={() => { props.navigation.navigate('Notification') }}>
                <Image source={require('../images/notification.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>

        }

    };